# Compile problems using ant and Java 1.7

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors, javac, java-7

I am trying to compile a code base using ant and the javac 1.7 compiler.
Currently, the code base compiles using the 1.6 compiler but when I switch to the 1.7 compiler, I get the following two oddities.

1) I get a warning: "warning: x is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release" where x is part of an internal proprietary API yet the line in the code it references does not reference x (nor does it reference x anywhere in the given file). This happened in a few places and the line it references is in a comment block.

2) The compile terminates with the following:

> ```
> [javac] The system is out of resources.
> [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
> [javac] java.lang.StackOverflowError
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:460)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:2053)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1565)
> ```

The relevant parameters that are in my ant script for javac are:

> ```
>       source="1.6" 
>         target="1.6" 
>         debug="on" 
>         debuglevel="lines,vars,source" 
>         nowarn="on" 
>         fork="yes" 
>         executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javac"
>         memorymaximumsize="1500m"
> ```

I tried changing the source and target versions. I also tried ajusting the memory size. It does not seem to help.

Comment: This is almost certainly a compiler bug. Try a newer version of Java 7?

Comment: It says `stackoverflow`. don't know why, but you can try to use a larger stack...

Comment: @SeanOwen Its only 1 update behind and I haven't found any known issues with the compiler via a Google search. Nevertheless, I will try what you suggest.

Comment: I tried adjusting the maximum memory and it still resulted in a stackoverflow. The 1.6 compiler has no issues with the same code base.

Comment: Are you increasing stack size or heap size? you need stack size: -Xss16M or something

Comment: @SeanOwen Increasing the stack size seems to work. The code base compiled. However, I still do not know why I was given a "x is internal proprietary API" warning on code which it didn't apply to.

Comment: The internal proprietary API warning sounds like a problem internal to the javac implementation; they are probably referencing a concrete implementation where they should be referencing an interface (spec). I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: It is kind of weird since the code base *does* have references to proprietary APIs, only not in the referenced source files. The 1.6 compiler doesn't do this. But it doesn't seem to be causing any problems.

Comment: This same error occured with Java 1.8 compiler. Increasing the stack size for javac  (-Xss16m) resolved it.

Comment: When we moved over to Java 8 we also had the same issue with the compiler as well. We have it set at 5 megs and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Just copying my comment to an answer, in case it turns out to be the answer.)

This may well be a Java 7 compiler bug. You can however give the compiler more memory by running `javac` with an argument like `-Xss16M`. This makes the thread stack size 16MB  vs default of 1MB. It may be a viable workaround.

The message about internal APIs is unrelated and can be ignored.

Comment: Specifically, in ant, specifying the following tag within javac will increase the stack size for the compiler.
`<compilerarg value= "-J-Xss5m" />`